# Regex Search and Replace spaces into underscores

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext

I have a file with a bunch of urls in it, I'm trying to search and replace the spaces and change them to underscores.

Here are some examples of the text, I just want to add the underscores to the file name.

```
<img style="width: 800px;" src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/6K5A8111 to print.jpg" alt="" />

<img style="width: 800px;" src="http://example.orgv/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Pizza Newbron Session 33psfb.jpg" alt="" />
```

I'm trying to do this with Sublimetext's search and replace using regex, but I can't seem to find the pattern to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no filenames in bold in your question.  Maybe the SO's syntax highlighting replaced it?   Where do you want to replace the spaces?  In the values inside the src attribute?

Comment: I want to replace it in the file name only. So **Pizza Newbron Session 33psfb.jpg** would turn into **Pizza_Newbron_Session_33psfb.jpg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think this one is possible in a reasonable way with a single replace. you might want to do globally replace all spaces with underscores, and then replace things like **"alt** with **" alt**, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As it so happens, I wrote a snippet a little while ago to replace spaces with underscores **within a selection**:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[${SELECTION/\s/_/g}]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Save this as `Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet`. Then, open `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following shortcut:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+-"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": 
    "Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet" } }
```

If this is your only custom key binding, you'll have to surround it with `[]` square brackets, so it looks like this:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+-"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": 
        "Packages/User/replace_space_with_underscore.sublime-snippet" } }
]
```

Now, you can highlight URLs containing spaces, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, and they'll be replaced with underscores. Definitely more work than a regex, but if Phillip Schmidt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219913/1426065) is true this may be the best way to do it. Good luck!

Comment: I was combing questions for about 45 minutes for this exact Sublime question and answer. This saved me **hours** of manually replacing spaces on a blog export I'm dealing with. Awesome little snippet you put together there, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your tags are all images, with a similar format to the tags above you can acomplish this in a single regular expression using positive and negative lookaheads.

```
\s(?=(\w+))(?!style|alt|src|\d+px)
```

**Positive Lookahead**

The first step in this regular expression is to find spaces followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.

```
\s(?=(\w+))
```

This expression will find following matches:

- Space between "img" and "style"
- Space between "width" and "800px"
- Space before src
- Spaces in the filename
- Space between filename and alt

The outer brackets allow of this regexp mean that the resulting matches will feed into the next portion of the expression i.e. the negative lookahead.

**Negative Lookahead**

This step negates the matches we are not interested in:

```
(?!style|alt|src|\d+px)
```

Another alternative, would be to use two positive lookaheads. This approach would give you a final regexp which looks like this:

```
\s(?=(\w+))(?=\w+(\s|\w)*\.[jpg])
```

The first portion of this expression is the same as above. The second lookahead is a bit more generic, looking for an alphanumeric character to start, followed by more alphanumeric characters or spaces multiple times followed by the .jpg extension.

**Second Positive Lookahead**

```
(?=\w+(\s|\w)*\.[jpg])
```